# Oracle Apex: How can I restrict a numeric field in a form to allow numbers only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5

I have an item in a form which is a number field and I want to somehow make sure that only numbers are accepted in the field. If users enter letters I want the field to reject it.

I already tried a validation but it was unsuccessful, is there anyway I get make this happen via a dynamic action with either a javascript code or a "pl/sql code"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing you should do except setting its type to **Number field**.

Yes, you can *type* anything you want into it, but Oracle won't *store* anything but numbers. It'll raise the "Field name must be numeric" error and stop.

Why would you want to reinvent the wheel?

---

If you must, try with dynamic action on that item (let's call it `P13_DEPTNO)`.

- When event: Key Press
- Selection type: Item
- Item: P13_DEPTNO
- True action: execute PL/SQL code (with "Items to submit": P13_DEPTNO):

  ```
  begin
    if not regexp_like(:P13_DEPTNO, '^\d+$')
    then
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Digits only');
    end if;
  end;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs the answer....

### enter this in the page JAVASCRIPT and GLOBAL variable declaration....

```
function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
  ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {
    textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      } else {
        this.value = "";
      }
    });
  });
}
```

---

Then go to the page item you want to restrict to numbers, and right click, add dynamic action, when: event: key press, selection type: items, items (item you have selected), add a true action...and have it execute JS CODE, then enter this code... replace the page item with your page item name...

```
setInputFilter(document.getElementById("PXX_XXXX"), function(value) {
  return /^-?\d*$/.test(value); });
```

And it will only let you enter numbers into the item.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a blog post for this usecase. Please refer the below link

https://akilramesh.blogspot.com/2021/10/allow-only-numbersdecimal-in-numbertext.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you do need to prevent users from inserting anything else but numbers.
Especially if this field is used for calculations. So you can use this https://www.foxinfotech.in/2020/02/oracle-apex-allow-only-integer-value-using-jquery.html